# Relation between rank of a group and rank of its subgroup.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let F be a free group and H be it's subgroup. Let $\rho$ denotes rank of a group, then

Case I: $\rho (F)=\infty$ and $[F:H]=\infty$.

Case II: $\rho (F)<\infty$ and $[F:H]=\infty$.

In both case what we can say about $\rho(H)$?

Comment: Are you talking of abelian groups here or in what sense are you using "rank"?

Comment: The rank of a free group is the number of elements in a free generating set. Free groups of rank at least are not abelian.

Comment: @DerekHolt: Dear Derek, A minor point, but when DonAntonio asked his question, the OP had left out that these were *free* groups.  (It was edited in later.)  Cheers,

Comment: Ah that explains things!

Answer (score 2):

The derived subgroup $D(\mathbb{F}_2)$ of $\mathbb{F}_2$ is an infinite-index subgroup of infinite rank, so $\mathbb{F}_2$ contains infinite-index subgroups of any rank (finite or infinite). Because any non-abelian free group has a subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_2$, such a free group has infinite-index subgroups of any rank.

Therefore, without more information about the subgroup $H$, we cannot say anything about its rank (unless $F$ is abelian, of course).

Comment: thats good, so what condition we need to impose for either case?

Comment: For example, we know that the rank of $H$ is infinite if $H$ is a normal subgroup, see Derek Holt's answer.

Answer (score 1):

One result is that if $N$ is a nontrivial normal subgroup of a free group $F$ with $|F:N| = \infty$, then $N$ is not finitely generated. More generally, if $1 \ne N \le E < F$ with $|F:E| = \infty$ and $N \lhd G$, then $\rho(E) = \infty$.